# How to historize each version of my object with Doctrine ?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

```
  public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new JobeetJobForm();
  }

  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod('post'));

    $this->form = new JobeetJobForm();

    $this->processForm($request, $this->form);

    $this->setTemplate('new');
  }

    protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $jobeet_job = $form->save();

      $this->redirect('job/edit?id='.$jobeet_job['id']);
    }
  }
```

I generated module with doctrine generator. I would like make: if i edit current Job and click Save then instead of save this edit i would like create new object job with new ID and same data as current edited Job. How can i make it? I would like make this same as wikipedia.

**EDIT:**
i dont know how to open action edit, edit few fields and click Save and instead save this changes i would like create new object. What i must edit in **processForm**?

Comment: Looks like you either need to start learning, reading, hire a trainer or hire a programmer if you want actual answers to your questions - this site might not fit that well such a broad request. - Probably you can make your question more specific?

Comment: Have you tried the Jobeet tutorials? These are available for Doctrine and Propel. Whilst you can do them yourself, a snapshotted copy of the Doctrine tutorial is available (fully completed) and I've supplied a (first 10 days) of Propel - both in the forum. I would encourage any 1.3/1.4 beginners to give them a go - they really do aid understanding, and are worth the time required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the goal of the [versionable behavior of Doctrine](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/behaviors.html#versionable).

Comment: thanks :) is possible use in template only ->getVersions for tshowing all version? I can't use this :(

Comment: Well the bad thing of using doctrine versionable (instead of the one from Propel) is that you don't have such (sooo) useful method. You have to build them on your own.

Answer (score 0):

When you need do keep versions with all related objects. You can serialize the object and keep it in database. Look at the JMSerializerBundle at github.

Comment: we are talking about sf1.4 not sf2.0 :)

Comment: damn StackOverflow tags ;]. In the Symfony 1.4 was a doctrine bahaviour: loggable :)